# Highchart performance slow on plotting live data

Tags: javascript, boost, highcharts

I am plotting live data in Highchart's(4.2.4) Line type chart for each second data i.e. 60 points for 1 min. and requirement is to collect each second data for long duration. I am using below code to add point in series. **The number of series I have is 20**. And for each series I have to add point per second. The **turboThreshold set for each series is also around 2000**. And **slicing should be done after 1000 points** data.

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(point, false, data > 1000?shift: false, false);
```

I see a very low performance my browser keeps hanging and also chart is very irresponsive after some time. What can I do for better performance? I have tried below stuff: 
1) Off the animation for series :

```
plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                animation:false,
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        lineWidthPlus: 0
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

2) Turn off animation and redrawing on addpoint to the chart

3) Turn off markers for series

4) Included boost.js module in application

```
 script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"
```

Comment: How's the performance without the `boost.js` module?

Comment: Its still slow I tried to add 20 series in the live data example of highchart [live data xample](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data)         (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/ )    and this also shows performance issue

Answer (score 0):

Without your actual code I can only speculate what you're doing, but my assumption is you're trying to redraw the chart every time you add a point, that would be 20 redraws per second, which is pretty excessive and will probably take more than 1 second to complete the redraws which means there will be new points added while old ones are still being drawn. Set the redraw to false on adding points and manually redraw every second or at random.

Example code:

```
$(function() {


  var series = function(i) {
    return {
      name: 'Random data '+i,
      data: (function() {
        // generate an array of random data
        var data = [],
          time = (new Date()).getTime(),
          i;

        for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
          data.push({
            x: time + i * 1000,
            y: Math.random()
          });
        }
        return data;
      }())
    };
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'line',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
          load: function() {
                        var chart = this;
            // set up the updating of the chart each second            
              setInterval(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {              
                var series = chart.series[i];
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                  y = Math.random();
                  series.addPoint([x, y], false, false,false);
                }
                chart.redraw();
              }, 1000);            
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 1,
          color: '#808080'
        }]
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: true
      },      
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      },
      series: [series(1), series(2),series(3), series(4),series(5), series(6),series(7), series(8),series(9), series(10),series(11), series(12),series(13), series(14),series(15), series(16),series(17), series(18),series(19), series(20)]
    });
  });
});
```

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/62k8sryc/1/

**NOTE**

Because this is JavaScript it heavily depends on browser build/version and machine specs.

Comment: Yes I am trying the same example you did in Fiddle and I am redrawing the chart after I am done with adding point to all the Series. In the Fiddle that you created only change would be chart type to ** line ** and export and markers, legends are all turned on. Also I noticed adding point to single series does not affect performance but doing that with 20 series does impact.

Comment: @piu it would help if you actually made a fiddle that indicated the problem. I've updated the code based on your suggested differences. I still don't see much of an issue, there's a slowdown, but nothing too extreme.

Comment: thanks @apokryfos for the changes you made. If you run the fiddle for say  long time, it kind of hangs the browser and highchart also becomes non responsive. Click on Export menu takes long. This is exactly the issue I have. Just to replicate the situation bit closer to my scenario. I have a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/priyankamore/g4qrL7yk/ on running this fiddle for long time the highchart becomes non responsive, zoom, export or any click on button takes too long. Apart from export I also have export-csv module included

Comment: Maybe you should start shifting earlier rather than after 1000. 1000 points means there will be 20 000 points to draw every second. That's a bit of a heavy job to get JavaScript/HTML/SVG to do, or perhaps you can redraw at random (e.g. every second with probability 20% or so). Could mess around with the parameters. Keep in mind, IE 8 users run a much much slower renderer than SVG so even 1000 points may be too much in that case

Comment: I think that you need to add boost.js module in your example and change boostThreshold parameter to smaller value. Boost module is working only if number of points is bigger than boostThreshold. See this example with boostThreshold set to 1: https://jsfiddle.net/g4qrL7yk/1/

Comment: @Grzegorz I tried with boost library it starts crashing after 30 mins as data is too long. The fiddle you had also crashes after 30 mins I observed

Comment: And @apokyfos my requirement is to keep at least 1000 previous data points so can't slice the data before 1000. Any other way out?

Comment: @piu I think your requirements are a bit too much for highcharts. Maybe you need to build your own solution or use another piece of software.